# How to find the number of bands in gdal in python?

Tags: python, gdal

i'm read tiff data using under code.

```
ds = 'path' , gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

and i find gdal API, i cna't find to read number of bands.

(ex) i have a 3 bands image, then read number of bands and return 3 in case)

is a any way to find  number of bands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The RasterCount attribute gives the band count.
Here's a simple example:

```
src_ds = gdal.Open("INPUT.tif")
if src_ds is not None: 
    print ("band count: " + str(src_ds.RasterCount))
```

Comment: thank you. i try to make a variable that mean RasterCount and it good work.